# "Equivalent" reference to "Quelques méthodes" by J-L. Lions

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, textbook-recommendation, books

I've just started learning about some methods to deal with parabolic equations, and in a lot of papers they refer to the book "Quelques méthodes de résolution des problèmes aux limites non linéaires" by J-L. Lions, which seems to be a sort of collection of such methods. The problem is that it's in french and there doesn't seem to be an english translation, and while I can kinda understand what he means, it's tiring having to worry both about difficult math and about an unknown language.

So I was wondering if  there were  "equivalent" books in english, which basically cover the same  methods  but in a language I can better understand.